# Spring AMQP Listener starts when autoStartup = false

Tags: spring-amqp

Recently faced a weird issue with Spring AMQP `@EventListener`.
Listener was declared like this, so autostartup was set to `false`

```
@RabbitListener(id = "MqMessageHandler", queues = "${rabbitMQ.in-queue-name}", autoStartup = "false")
public void receiveMessage(Message message) {
```

After application is fully initialized and i get a response from some other service, i'm manually starting the listener like this

```
MessageListenerContainer mqMessageHandler = registry.getListenerContainer(HANDLER_ID);
mqMessageHandler.start();
```

But it appears that listener is still starting on context initialization.
Digging a bit in the code i found this piece of code inside `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry`

```
    /**
     * Start the specified {@link MessageListenerContainer} if it should be started
     * on startup or when start is called explicitly after startup.
     * @param listenerContainer the container.
     * @see MessageListenerContainer#isAutoStartup()
     */
    private void startIfNecessary(MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer) {
        if (this.contextRefreshed || listenerContainer.isAutoStartup()) {
            listenerContainer.start();
        }
    }
```

That means that listener will be started once `ContextRefreshed` event is fired.
I'd expect the condition to be
`this.contextRefreshed && listenerContainer.isAutoStartup()`
so `&&` instead of `||` and then it should work as expected.

Does anybody knows if the condition is correct, and my assumptions are wrong?
Spring AMQP version is `2.3.1` but the same i saw in `2.3.10`

As a workaround for now i'm registering listener manually like this

```
        MessageListenerContainer mqMessageHandler = registry.getListenerContainer(HANDLER_ID);
        if (Objects.isNull(mqMessageHandler)) {
            SimpleRabbitListenerEndpoint endpoint = new SimpleRabbitListenerEndpoint();
            endpoint.setQueueNames(inQueueName);
            endpoint.setMessageListener(this.mqMessageHandler);
            endpoint.setId(HANDLER_ID);

            registry.registerListenerContainer(endpoint, factory);
            mqMessageHandler = registry.getListenerContainer(HANDLER_ID);
        }
        mqMessageHandler.start();
```

Comment: Auto startup is only considered during application context initialization (it is a feature of `SmartLifecycle`).

How are you registering the listener after the context was refreshed?

Comment: @GaryRussell, i've updated the question with a workaround i used with manual registering of the listener and starting it. If the behavior in `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` is correct, then probably i didn't understand it well. and no more questions from my side.

Comment: I think we should add a property to the registry `useAutoStartUpAfterRefresh` or similar; please open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you @GaryRussell, will create an issue!
Issue created: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after investigation it was found that:

1. Spring AMQP works as expected and didn't start listener on startup as expected.
2. In my case it was an issue that `context.refresh()` and `context.start()` was called manually from the code of in-hous platform. In that case `contextRefreshed` flag in `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` was set to true, and during 2nd call to `startIfNecessary` (beacause of `context.start()`) listener was started.